# Calculate Total DateDif Average Between 2 Columns (start, end) according to year expressed in days, hours, minutes

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates, google-sheets-timestamp

I'm having trouble getting a formula to work to calculate the total average time between times (start and end).
Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X8EdejdzXMQg6x8k7ig5Jcdvdh2xQegu9lq4i6088ME

`DateDif` is the function that will do this individually (but only for days), I know using the `TEXT` function with `DateDif` could work (in my head). I've had issues getting it to work with `Average`, segmenting by years:

```
=AVERAGE(DATEDIF(A2:A37,B2:B37,"d"))
```

I've also tried writing the following which hasn't worked, with me now confusing myself and head scratching as I've not managed to find a solution online:

```
=SUMIFS($B:$B,$A:$A,">=2020/01/01",$A:$A,"<2021/01/01")/COUNTIFS($A:$A,">=2020/01/01",$A:$A,"<2021/01/01")
```

The result I'm after is to have the total average duration for each year, reported in `F12:H12`.

I hope this makes sense and I've not confused you more than myself!

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. 
Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formulas:

For `2020` use in cell `D2`

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(ArrayFormula(IF(YEAR($B$2:$B$37)=2020,($B$2:$B$37-$A$2:$A$37)))),0)
```

You will get a number like `4.475757576`. Format the cell as `Duration` to get the hours *(if not interested leave it as is)*.

Following that, you can use the following formula in cell `D3`

```
=INT(D2)&"D "& HOUR(MOD(D2,1))&"H "&MINUTE(MOD(D2,1))&"M "&SECOND(MOD(D2,1))&"S"
```

Changing the year you get corresponding results.

*Please adjust ranges and cells to your needs.*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`AVERAGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093615)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`YEAR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093061)
- [`MOD`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093497)
- [`INT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093490)
- [`HOUR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093045)
- [`MINUTE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093048)
- [`SECOND`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093054)

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

However I needed to query a date range by Type (col C), and tried the following in row 14 (J-M): 

=IFERROR(AVERAGE(ArrayFormula(IFS($C2:$C,"A",YEAR($A2:$A)>=2020/1/1,($B2:$B-$A2:$A),YEAR($A2:$A)<2020/4/1,($B2:$B-$A2:$A)))),0)

=IFERROR(AVERAGE(ArrayFormula(IFS($C2:$C,"B",YEAR($A2:$A)>=2020/1/1,($B2:$B-$A2:$A),YEAR($A2:$A)<2020/4/1,($B2:$B-$A2:$A)))),0)

...

Can you take help here again if possible please?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: =ArrayFormula(AVERAGE(FILTER(B2:B-A2:A,C2:C="A",B2:B>=DATEVALUE("2020-1-1"),B2:B<DATEVALUE("2020-4-1"))))